# Multiple usercontrol projects in MSVS08

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I'm rather new to C# development so that's why I ask that question:
I have several projects in my solution. Most of them are UserControls. Some of them depends on mine other UC projects (included in the solution). For the sake of simplicity let's say the dependecies of projects are like that:
A->B->C

A is a main app., B&C are UCs.

How shall I configure my projects to allow:
1) making changes to C when it has been used alread in B or A
2) have no problems with using B or C after they change.

Thanks for you advices.

Answer (score 2):

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7519/16168797.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7519/16168797.jpg)

Right Click 'Solution' > project dependencies

- Select the dependencies for the projects the way you want
- Remeber to select the build order for projects in your solution

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the solution and configure the "Project Dependencies".
Configure A to depend on B and C, and then configure B to depend on C.